# In a simulated linear regression why is the standard deviation proportional to the square root of the variable?

Tags: r, statistics

In [An Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf), Appendix A is "A sample session" designed to give a first introduction to R.

It includes a simulation of a linear regression:

```
x <- 1:20
```

Make x = (1, 2, …, 20).

```
w <- 1 + sqrt(x)/2
```

A ‘weight’ vector of standard deviations.

```
dummy <- data.frame(x=x, y= x + rnorm(x)*w)

dummy
```

Make a data frame of two columns, x and y, and look at it.

```
fm <- lm(y ~ x, data=dummy)

summary(fm)
```

Fit a simple linear regression and look at the analysis. With y to the left of the tilde, we are modelling y dependent on x.

The vector `w` is created so as to provide error values to be added to the `y` values. I can understand that the standard deviations should be larger for larger values of `y`. But it would seem that they should be in proportion to the `y` value. So why the square root? Also, if the `y` value is added to an error value, should they not be dimensionaly the same?

I must be missing something basic. So my question is: Why are the standard deviations in a linear regression proportional to the square root, rather than to the variable itself?

Comment: *I can understand that the standard deviations should be larger for larger values of `y`*. Why would that be? Data can be homoscedastic. In that **example**, the square root is a way to increase the errors as `x` grows, yes, but in the general case the standard deviations in a linear regression are not proportional to the square root, nor to the variable itself. I am voting to close as needing more focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the point of the exercise because you stopped before you got to the most important part.

With standard linear regression, you want to find the line of best fit between x and y. This line will have the formula y = ax + b, where *a* is the gradient of the line and *b* is the intercept. Of course, your individual data points won't lie exactly on this line, but will be scattered above and below it. The vertical distance from each point to the best-fit line will be the *residual* of the model with respect to that point.

The assumption in a straightforward linear regression is that the residuals will be normally distributed, with a mean of zero and a fixed standard deviation. The value of the standard deviation doesn't get bigger with larger values of x or of y. However, data don't always have to behave that way, and sometimes the standard deviation will be dependent on the x value (think of measurements of distances: you can measure the edge of a table to the nearest milimeter, but your error will be much bigger if you are measuring the distance between mountain peaks). This property, of the standard deviation changing as a function of x, is known as *heteroscadisity*.

We need to account for heteroscadisity when running a linear regression. Otherwise, the larger deviations at one end of our line might affect our estimate of the line's gradient and intercept. If we know the standard deviation gets larger with larger values of x, we need to give less weight to the measurements at larger values of x.

The `w` variable is effectively there to show that the `lm` function can handle heteroscadisity via the `weights` parameter.

Here is the full example:

```r
w <- 1 + sqrt(x)/2 # A ‘weight’ vector of standard deviations.
dummy <- data.frame(x=x, y= x + rnorm(x)*w)
dummy 
# Make a data frame of two columns, x and y, and look at it.

fm <- lm(y ~ x, data=dummy) 
summary(fm)
# Fit a simple linear regression and look at the analysis. 
# With y to the left of the tilde, we are modelling y dependent on x.


fm1 <- lm(y ~ x, data=dummy, weight=1/w^2) 
summary(fm1)
# Since we know the standard deviations, we can do a weighted regression.
```

The last snippet is the whole reason for including the `w` variable.